# how to run different pentaho transformations depending on the file name passed in parameter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pentaho-spoon

i have a java web application that triggers a pentaho job execution by passing the name of the file to treat . that name should be captured and depending on that name a specific transformation process will be executed .
so how can i choose the transformation to execute depending on the parameter passed ? 
i want to use like switch case , but switch case is only used inside the transformation itself. 
Im want like a switch case to select jobs : depending on the parameter choose the correspending job

Comment: u looks pretty..